# Lucene.net version 3.4.0 is not available

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Hi i am looking for how to search relational data in Lucene.net i found the below link

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html

and i came to know that we can use BlockJoinQuery which is introduced in Lucene version 3.4.0 but there is no Lucene.net version 3.4.0 as in Lucene, the latest Lucene.net version is 3.0.3 but there is no BlockJoinQuery option how can i do relational search ?

I appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You encountered the typical problem when dealing with ports of software to another language and most likely you will need to patiently wait to get the feature or help porting it

Answer (score 0):

Your link is about `Lucene` and not `Lucene.net`.

The archive of Apache Lucene : http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/

The archive of Apache Lucene.net (no new version since december 2012) : http://www.apache.org/dist/lucenenet/

A lot of things have been added to Lucene since 3.0.